# PHP - Is there any way to extract, list and categorize names of all variables, classes and objects in a system?

Tags: php

I have a CMS written in object oriented PHP. The system has many PHP files, folders, templates, and etc. Is there an easy way to extract and categorize names of all variables, classes and objects in the system quickly?

Comment: So, you want to scan through the entire codebase and document all variables, classes, etc.?

Comment: yes exactly, and then start to refactor the codes.

Comment: I think http://phpdoc.org/ may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have used PHP_Beautifier in the past.  It scans a .php file and extracts all the functions and variable names and tries to identify type if possible from the functions themselves.

http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/